# Why there are people who want to have multi-accounts in Ethereum?

Tags: security, addresses

Why there are people who want to have multi-accounts in Ethereum?
I notice that in the Ethereum ecosystem, more and more people own more than one account, what motivates them to create more than one account in the Ethereum ecosystem?

Answer (score 0):

many people like to separate their addresses according to the need/operations. it is more about personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a privacy issue. You may not want to show your entire financial history to any person/company you interact with.
Imagine paying your rent or a friend, and they would immediately know your net worth and all your past financial transactions.